# Move file to a folder in current directory in Linux

Tags: files

How to move file from a directory to a folder in current directory? I tried this command but it didn't work.

```
move /home/document/query/template.xlsm $CWD/accuracy_results_folder
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command for moving (and renaming) is `mv`, not `move`.

The current directory is `.` (a single dot). The value `"$PWD"` is the absolute path of the current directory, but that is *very rarely* used in commands on the command line. The shell does not generally use the variable `CWD`, and its value is likely empty, which means that `$CWD/accuracy_results_folder` would be the same as `/accuracy_results_folder`, which is the absolute path of something at the top of the directory tree.

Instead:

```bsh
mv /home/document/query/template.xlsm ./accuracy_results_folder/
```

You may omit `./` in this case. A path that starts with anything other than `/` will always be relative to the current directory.

```bsh
mv /home/document/query/template.xlsm accuracy_results_folder/
```

The trailing `/` at the end of the directory name is not needed either. However, adding it stops the command from creating the *file* `accuracy_results_folder` if the directory does not exist.